# Missing return statement required return type: Integer Apex

Tags: apex, compile-error

When I'm trying to delete some records and get the count of number of records deleted, I'm facing below error:

> Missing return statement required return type: Integer

```
public static integer DeleteRecord(HDFC_Customer_Details__c client){
    try{
        integer numOfRecDeleted;
        if (client!=null){
            list<HDFC_Customer_Details__c> recstoDelete= new list<HDFC_Customer_Details__c>();
            list<HDFC_Customer_Details__c> recs = [SELECT id from HDFC_Customer_Details__c where First_Name__c=:client.First_Name__c];
            for(HDFC_Customer_Details__c rec: recs){
                recstoDelete.add(rec);
            }
            
            delete recstoDelete;
             numOfRecDeleted=  recstoDelete.size();
           system.debug(numOfRecDeleted);
            return numOfRecDeleted;
                    }
         
        }
    catch(Exception ex){
        //handle error here
    }
      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `try` block currently  *only* returns anything from the `if` block. The compiler needs to know you will always `return` something. It is a bit odd to return the success count, but the minimal change to your code to correct the structure would be to put the `return` statement outside of any of those blocks, at the very end of your method.

```
Integer successCount;
try
{
    // delete logic
}
catch (...)
{
    // error handling
}
return successCount;
```

Comment: Or, you can return a value from the catch as well. As long as both try and catch return, that's acceptable to the compiler.

Comment: You would still need to move the `return` outside the `if`. Sure you can put in multiple `return` statements, but I find it less clean.

Answer (score 1):

Each branch in your code must return something. One possible way to write that is as follows:

```
public static integer DeleteRecord(HDFC_Customer_Details__c client){
    try{
        HDFC_Customer_Details__c[] records = [SELECT Id FROM HDFC_Customer_Details__c WHERE First_Name__c = :client.First_Name__c];
        delete records;
        return records.size();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // We can indicate an error here
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to copy records from one list to another, or anything complicated like that. The above code does everything yours does, but far more efficiently.

Note that exceptions like CPU time out or heap limits can still throw uncaught exceptions, so whatever code is calling this might need to account for that.